# Formulario não faz o action

Tags: php, html

Criei um formulário onde quero inserir dados no banco, mas não quero que o utilizador insira os dados, logo coloquei `display:block` no form. No entanto quando clico no botão não acontece nada.

O código do `form` é o seguinte:

```
<form role="form" action="inserir_pedido.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="id_servico" id="id_servico" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" name="nome_servico" id="nome_servico" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" name="horas" id="horas" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" name="id_profissional" id="id_profissional" style="display:none;" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>">
  <input type="text" name="id_utilizador" id="id_utilizador" style="display:none;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Enviar email</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Altere no button: `type="submit"`. Outra dica, campos que você quer atribuir dados mas não quer que sejam visiveis ou editaveis, é interessante você usa-los como `hidden`, como no caso desse input de name id_profissional. Se não quer que seja visivel, mas quer poder capturar seu value, não precisa de css, basta alterar  `type="hidden"`

Answer (score 1):

Como o @DiegoFelipe falou, quando você deseja pegar o valor de um campo, você não precisa utilizar o `Display:none`, basta mudar o tipo do campo para `hidden` que ele não será exibido para o usuário. Ficaria mais ou menos assim um campo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_servico" id="id_servico">
```

E para que o seu formulário seja submetido, basta mudar o tipo do botão para `submit`, ficando assim:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Enviar email</button>
```

A solução completa ficaria assim:

```
<form role="form" action="inserir_pedido.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_servico" id="id_servico">
  <input type="hidden" name="nome_servico" id="nome_servico">
  <input type="hidden" name="horas" id="horas">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_profissional" id="id_profissional" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_utilizador" id="id_utilizador">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Enviar email</button>
</form>
```